# Does Street View Static API support markers

Tags: google-street-view-static-api

Are markers supported in Street View Static API? I am not getting a marker back, and I see no documentation provided for using markers with street view static images.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation from Google indicates that street view markers are supported:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview#markers_within_street_view

an example is:

```
// Create a marker at the Eiffel Tower
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.858, longitude: 2.294)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

// Add the marker to a GMSPanoramaView object named panoView
marker.panoramaView = panoView

// Add the marker to a GMSMapView object named mapView
marker.map = mapView
```